# How to verify path variable with react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm defining routes for a React project in a way that the URL looks like http://something.com/en-us/home or http://something.com/fr-ca/home by doing:

```
<Route path="/:language/home" render={() => <Home/>}/>
```

In planning for a case where the path variable ":language" is a not a real language (i.e. redirect http://something.com/xyz/home to http://something.com/en-us/home), I originally invoked the method `setDefaultLanguage` within `componentDidMount`, which was intended to refresh the page with the browser's language code. Instead, this method refreshes the page each time that it mounts.

```
checkLangInMasterList(code) {
    let index = Object.keys(langMasterList).indexOf(code);
    // langMasterList is a JSON file with codes for 15
    // languages that the website will be offered in

    return index === -1 ? false : true;
}

setDefaultLanguage() {
    let browserLanguage = navigator.language || navigator.browserLanguage;
    let pathnames = window.location.pathname.split("/");
    // i.e. pathnames would look like
    // ["", "xyz", "home"]

    if (checkLangInMasterList(pathnames[1]) !== -1) {
        return;
    } else if (checkLangInMasterList(browserLanguage) === -1) {
        window.location = `/en-us/${pathnames[2]}`;
    } else if (
        checkLangInMasterList(pathnames[1]) === -1 &&
        checkLangInMasterList(browserLanguage) !== -1
    ) {
        window.location = `/${browserLanguage}/${pathnames[2]}`;
    }
}
```

If the browser's language code doesn't exist (either at all or within the allowed languages list), how do I properly handle a redirect to either the user's browser language (if supported in our list) or to `en-us`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `checkLangInMasterList` return a boolean not -1.
Your code should look like this:

```
if (!checkLangInMasterList(pathnames[1])) {
    // do stuff here
}
```

also, if the path variable equals the browser language you should stop the redirect.

So according to the logic you want here is how it will look like:

```
if (checkLangInMasterList(pathnames[1]) {
    return
}
if (checkLangInMasterList(browserLanguage) {
    window.location = `/${browserLanguage}/${pathnames[2]}`
} else {
    window.location = `/${en-us}/${pathnames[2]}`
}
```